# Ubuntu Font Family and Mac OS X confusing font name and font

Tags: fonts, macosx, ubuntu-font-family

I really like the Ubuntu Font Family, and frequently use it in my documents. At school, I want to be able to use the font family so my documents that make at home using Ubuntu show up correctly at school. However, we do not have permission to use Font View (which also allows you to install fonts), so I copied the .ttf files for the Ubuntu font into the `/home/Library/Fonts` directory. The fonts now show up in the list of available fonts.

However, when I click on Ubuntu Light, it uses the Ubuntu font, and when I click on Ubuntu, it uses the Ubuntu Light font. This is irritating because my documents that I make on my home computer show up in the opposite font at school, and documents I make at school show up in the opposite font at home. This is really irritating. My school uses Mac OSX 10.4. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: This happens with Windows too, so it's something wrong with the font that Ubuntu put on the website.

Comment: This issue is present on a Ubuntu system also. When Font Viewer is used to compare Ubuntu-R.ttf (regular) and Ubuntu-L.ttf (light), the Light typeface is definitely lighter than the Regular typeface but when compared in Libreoffice Ubuntu light is the heavier typeface. This also shows up on the Ubuntu fonts web page.

Comment: As an experiment I tried switching the names around. It did not change anything.

Comment: Hmm... so this is a recognized problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, this sounds like a known problem with the Ubuntu Font Family. I would suggest [filing a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) on Launchpad against this [project](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-font-family) so the developers know and can try doing something about it.

Comment: Also, forgot to mention: if you do report a bug for this, it'd be helpful if you could post a link to the bug report back here so others will be able to find it easily and mark themselves as affected. Thanks!